# Find and print only the first ORF in fasta

Tags: python

How to find only the first start_codon for each frame. In the code below it is giving me all start_codon position.

```
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio import SeqIO
def test(seq, start, stop):
    start = ["ATG"]
    start_codon_index = 0
    for frame in range(0,3):
        for i in range(frame, len(seq), 3):
            current_codon = seq[i:i+3]                            
            if current_codon in start:
                start_codons.append(start_codon_index)
    return start_codons

f = open("a.fa","r")
start = ["ATG"]
for record in SeqIO.parse(f,"fasta"):
    seq=record.seq
    name=record.id
    start_codons=test(seq, start, stop)
    print name, start_codons
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a DNA string and you want to find the first occurrence of an "ATG" sequence, the easiest is to just do:

```
DNA = "ACCACACACCATATAATGATATATAGGAAATG"

print(DNA.find("ATG"))
```

Prints out `15`, note that the indexing in python starts from 0

In case you consider nucleotide triplets as well:

```
DNA = "ACCACACACCATATAATGATATATAGGAAATG"
for i in range(0, len(DNA), 3):
    if DNA[i:i+3] == "ATG":
        print(i)
        break
```

Returns `15` as well.

Comment: thanks, however it is not so straightforward, since I need to consider 3 frames, meaning in frame 1, it takes triplets starting from pos0,in frame 2, from pos1 and frame 3 from pos2, each time the triplets will change. OK, i added for frame in range(0,3). what if I need it to be printed like name (start1, start2,start3)?

Comment: If you need all the start positions just drop the `break`

Comment: No...I just 3 start position for each frame...my code above gives me all position. OK, I solved. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will find it very easy with regex and re.match, since re.match will try to match the begining of the string and return the value, if it does not match it will return None.

For example, if you have a sequence to be read:

```
sequence = 'ATGTTGTGAGCGGATGGTTTAAT'
import re
index = 0
while index < len(sequence) - 6: # condiering that the least ORF contains 6 nts
    match = re.match('(ATG(?:\S{3})*?T(?:AG|AA|GA))', sequence[index:])
    if match:
        print('Find the first one', match.group())
        index += len(match.group())
        break
    else:
        index += 1
```

Then you will get the output:

```
'Find the first one ATGTTGTGA'
```